# Prevent intermediate Maven artifacts from being uploaded

Tags: java, maven

I have a project creating some FAT jar to be used via webstart loaded from an ear. This leads to the following Maven projects in a multi-module project

- jar project creating the FAT jar
- war project creating the webstart war
- ear file containing the server application and the war file for webstart

The jar and war artifacts are only used as intermediate artifacts to be able to create the ear artifact. However, Maven handles them as artifacts and so they are always uploaded to Nexus.

Since the jar is getting real fat, I would like to avoid uploading it 3 times to nexus for each build. Is there a way to avoid this? I can think of two ways:

- Moving that three projects to one pom file
- Some flag / option / whatever telling Maven to handle artifacts as intermediate artifacts not being deployed or installed

Does something like this or any other solution to my problem exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a multi-module project, you can set `<maven.deploy.skip>` to `true` in the projects where artifacts should not be deployed.

Comment: That easy! Thanks!